# Periodically long running background task

Tags: android, background-task

I would like to perform the following tasks on every 30 minutes interval -

- MNC, MCC, LAC & Cell ID
- Display it to user &
- Send these information to a remote server via HTTP request.

During this time, the app may/may not be in front.

My question is, is IntentService a good idea to execute the above tasks? 
Or, any other idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041573/android-create-a-background-thread-that-runs-periodically-and-does-ui-tasks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to build a sync mechanism. Best approach would be using [Sync Adapters](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html) which is designed for these situations.

But for using sync adapters, you need to change your login mechanism to work with [AbstractAccountAuthenticator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AbstractAccountAuthenticator.html) if you are not on it.

Good luck

Emre

Comment: Its an advanced topic and takes time to get concept. Dont give up ;)