# How can I speed up my app?

Tags: android

I am developing an app which is have rest API calls and 4 tabs using page sliding tab strip but my problem is when I move tabs from left to right it's too late to display page and struck for 5 to 8 seconds why? and here i'm using fragments. my app is simply like what's app.

Thanks in advance.`

```
class GetTasks extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (response != null && response.length() > 0) {

            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                if (jsonArray != null && jsonArray.length() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    Task task = gson.fromJson(jsonObj.toString(),Task.class);
                    tasklist.add(task);

                }
                }else{
                    nodata.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }else{
            nodata.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        Collections.reverse(tasklist);
        ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(tasklist);
        list_view.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            String response = Util.excuteGet(params[0]);
            return response;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}`
```

Comment: You're doing too many things on the main thread.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472383/how-can-i-run-code-on-a-background-thread-on-android

Comment: see below answer .

Comment: You should do the parsing in `doInBackground()` and NOT in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Use OkHttp or Volley libraries instead of AsyncTask

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to do that is to use **AsyncTask** (Background Service). **recycler view** in place of listviews. While the download speed depends on the connection, you can give indication to the user using the **dialog or progress bar**.

Comment: Try to Avoid blocking main Thread & unnecessary invalidations
Use RelativeLayouts in a high hierarchy level
Avoid Nested weights in LinearLayouts 
Avoid Creating Unnecessary Objects
Use Static Final For Constants.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem not about performance improvement, you just misused AsyncTask. But, as to performance, on Udacity.com you can find not bad course on this theme https://www.udacity.com/course/android-performance--ud825