# Making the phone silent on nearing a particular location even app is in the background

Tags: android, location, silent, vibration

I'm making an Android app which would make the phone go on silent or in vibration mode at a user defined location.

I've learned how to toggle between silent mode to normal mode and to get the current location.

I want to know how can I turn my phone silent at a particular location even the app is not running?. Any help appreciated and atleast provide me some stuff..,Thank you

Comment: Can't control the phone without the app running. It at least needs to be running in the background I think.

Comment: @BillyFerguson is right. and as far as i knw Vinod imust be having a service to continuously fetch location, so what you can do is if you are not having app running in background, first make a service for fetching location and when trigger is reached do the desired thing.

Comment: You can run things in the background while the app is open, but the phone is locked. Just put a radius around the location you want and check if your current location is within that radius. Once it is, run the code you wrote to make the phone go silent.

Comment: @BillyFerguson can you give me some reference link .?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472383/how-can-i-run-code-on-a-background-thread-on-android

Comment: @BillyFerguson is there any open source code available .?

Comment: That link was like 4 lines of code...