# Implement unstoppable background service in react native

Tags: android, performance, firebase, react-native, react-native-fcm

I am trying to run a unstoppable background service in react native which will continuously listen for messages via Socket.io from server.

For this I found several solutions with several problems

1. **Use FCM**

   > The problem with method is that first I have to listen for FCM event than connect to my server and get the data(Messages + images + Videos). And I don't want to use firebase for my app as its expensive and don't want to store my user data (Mainly images) and handle user auth.
2. **Use [react-native-background-fetch](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-fetch/)**

   > This thing is pretty good but it only allow to run single job every 5 minutes and if your service is killed by android than you are gone
3. **Use [Headless JS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android)**

   > To be honest I cannot understand its documentation

Please tell me what to s I am confused and amazed that there is no proper way to handle this
TIA
regards

Comment: What do you mean by "unstoppable background service"? Android doesn't allow such a thing, in order to prevent apps from draining battery and data. Best case, Anrdoid allows a foreground service, which requires a status notification, but it can still be killed by Android if it needs the memory.

Comment: Got it. Then how come apps like facebook whatsapp snapchat receive notification without opening it. And how does FCM works?

Comment: Then what should I do to listen y text messages from server socket?

Comment: That's just push messaging.  FCM does that.  The plumbing for that is handled by services the device, both Android and iOS.

Comment: Can you please tell me that how FCM exactly does that?

Comment: This has been discussed a lot already on stack overflow and other sites - do some searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for that you need to learn native-modules and react-native-bridge and some basics of android and ios services.
Here is the link for you reference.

https://medium.com/reactbrasil/how-to-create-an-unstoppable-service-in-react-native-using-headless-js-93656b6fd5d1

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can implement a native module java/objective-c
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android

and run a background thread like this 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31549559/5754159